# Minimum velocity to go through a loop

Tags: classical-mechanics

I came across the classic result regarding the minimum velocity required to perform a loop. My book however, asked me of the minimum velocity required for a block of ice on a frictionless surface (as follows) to reach the topmost point of the loop, which seems like a different question to the minimum velocity to cover the loop and I assumed it kose all velocity at the top of the loop, such that I could set KE at the bottom to the PE at the top. Which would lead to the minimum velocity being the square root of 4times the radius times the gravity, however it seems that we cannot assume that the velocity of the ice block is zero at the top ost point, can someone please explain why I cannot set KE to PE for this case?

[image: loop de loop]

Comment: You _can_ set KE=PE and solve. You know that the velocity it has at the top is $v=\sqrt{gr}$ and so to find the velocity it needs to make a loop, use conservation of energy.

Answer (score 1):

We can't do it because if the velocity at the top is zero, it would instantly drop to the ground below, defeating our purpose of going roundabout. We can write three equations:

At bottom:
$$\frac{mv_o^2}{r}=N_{up}-mg$$
At Top:
$$\frac{mv_1^2}{r}=N_{down}+mg$$
Energy equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2=\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2+mg(2r)$$

For $v_1=v_{min}$, we need to reduce the normal reaction of due to track at the top to zero $N_{down}=0$.

Solving will yield our answer.

Hope it helps, ask for any doubts.

Comment: But I thought all we need to do is get to the top point of the circle? And so we wouldn't need to worry about going around it, so thats why I didn't think it would pose a problem... And also in the case where it would go straight up in say a line, or a sloped line, this should technically work, so I didn't understand why it wouldn't be the case for a circle, it would simply reach the top point and fall down.